# Slow SMB (FreeNas) performance experience on single client machine running Windows 10 Pro

Tags: networking, performance, smb

I am experiencing a strange behavior on my laptop running Windows 10 Pro.

Copying a file from a shared folder (SMB) offered by a FreeNas server (connected to the switch by a LAGG on dual-gigabit NICs) I can see that the copy operations starts very fast (80 or 90 MB/s) and after some seconds it slows down to 13 or 14 MB/s and the fluctuates in this range.

I tried both on Wi-Fi (Aruba networks 5GHz) and cabled directly into the switch (DELL 24 ports gigabit)

All the other clients (9) in the same office do not show this behavior and can download the same file at 100 MB/s without hiccups

I think this could be related to some software configuration in my laptop, but I don't know where to start investigating

Comment: Where are you copying to? Have you checked the CPU load? Do you have security software installed that may interfere?

Comment: - I am copying to my internal 512GB M.2 SSD
- CPU load is floating between 5 and 8%
- I have Cylance Protect and Windows Security